# Appending data row from one dataframe to another with respect to date

Tags: python, pandas

I am brand new to pandas and working with two dataframes. My goal is to append the non-date values of df_ls (below) column-wise to their nearest respective date in df_1. Is the only way to do this with a traditional for-loop or is their some more effective built-in method/function. I have googled this extensively without any luck and have only found ways to append blocks of dataframes to other dataframes. I haven't found a way to search through a dataframe and append a row in another dataframe at the nearest respective date. See example below:

Example of **first dataframe** (lets call it **df_ls**):

```
       DATE          ALBEDO_SUR B13_RATIO  B23_RATIO B1_RAW    B2_RAW  
0      1999-07-04    0.070771   1.606958   1.292280  0.128069  0.103018   
1      1999-07-20    0.030795   2.326290   1.728147  0.099020  0.073595   
2      1999-08-21    0.022819   2.492871   1.762536  0.096888  0.068502   
3      1999-09-06    0.014613   2.792271   1.894225  0.090590  0.061445   
4      1999-10-08    0.004978   2.781847   1.790768  0.089291  0.057521   
5      1999-10-24    0.003144   2.818474   1.805257  0.090623  0.058054   
6      1999-11-09    0.000859   3.146100   1.993941  0.092787  0.058823   
7      1999-12-11    0.000912   2.913604   1.656642  0.097239  0.055357   
8      1999-12-27    0.000877   2.974692   1.799949  0.098282  0.059427   
9      2000-01-28    0.000758   3.092533   1.782112  0.095153  0.054809   
10     2000-03-16    0.002933   2.969185   1.727465  0.083059  0.048322   
11     2000-04-01    0.016814   2.366437   1.514110  0.089720  0.057398   
12     2000-05-03    0.047370   1.847763   1.401930  0.109767  0.083290   
13     2000-05-19    0.089432   1.402798   1.178798  0.137965  0.115936   
14     2000-06-04    0.056340   1.807828   1.422489  0.118601  0.093328
```

Example of **second dataframe** (let's call it **df_1**)

```
    Sample Date  Value 
0    2000-05-09   1.68  
1    2000-05-09   1.68  
2    2000-05-18   1.75  
3    2000-05-18   1.75  
4    2000-05-31   1.40 
5    2000-05-31   1.40 
6    2000-06-13   1.07
7    2000-06-13   1.07
8    2000-06-27   1.49
9    2000-06-27   1.49
10   2000-07-11   2.29
11   2000-07-11   2.29
```

In the end, my goal is to have something like this (Note the appended values are values closest to the Sample Date, even though they dont match up perfectly):

```
    Sample Date  Value  ALBEDO_SUR B13_RATIO  B23_RATIO B1_RAW    B2_RAW  
0    2000-05-09   1.68  0.047370   1.847763   1.401930  0.109767  0.083290
1    2000-05-09   1.68  0.047370   1.847763   1.401930  0.109767  0.083290
2    2000-05-18   1.75  0.089432   1.402798   1.178798  0.137965  0.115936   
3    2000-05-18   1.75  0.089432   1.402798   1.178798  0.137965  0.115936   
4    2000-05-31   1.40  0.056340   1.807828   1.422489  0.118601  0.093328   
5    2000-05-31   1.40  0.056340   1.807828   1.422489  0.118601  0.093328   
6    2000-06-13   1.07  ETC....    ETC....    ETC ...
7    2000-06-13   1.07
8    2000-06-27   1.49
9    2000-06-27   1.49
10   2000-07-11   2.29
11   2000-07-11   2.29
```

Thanks for any and all help. As I said I am new to this and I have experience with this sort of thing in MATLAB but PANDAS is a new to me.

Thanks

Comment: I'm reasonably ignorant of this, but I thought use dictionaries. But the conversion to and back would be rather inefficient I'd imagine.

Comment: I can tell you from experience that this will need to be performed in some kind of for loop/apply method. As there are no exact matches you have to find the appropriate index value to set the new column values, I would use `numpy.searchsorted` or you could use a filter, in `0.15.1` I think you can do some fancy filtering if you pass a range but not sure it applies to dates, worth a try though.